# htacces and the nice urls

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo, nice

I have this link formats on my webpage:

```
https://mypage.com/index2.php?page=registration
https://mypage.com/index2.php?page=food&category=1
```

The first type is replaced as this:

```
https://mypage.com/registration (works well)
```

And I would like to format the second as:

```
https://mypage.com/food/1 (doesn't work, the page is loaded, but the images don't)
```

So I created the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)?$ index2.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^food/([^/.]+)?$ index2.php?page=food&category=$1 [L]
```

But doesn't work. :(
What is wrong with this? And where are the pictures?
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (doesn't work, the page is loaded, but the images don't)

Probably because your links are relative (doesn't begin with a `/`) and when you have that extra slash after `/food`, it changes the URL base (tries to access images in a non-existent `/food/` directory). Change all your links to absolute URLs or add a base in the page header:

```
<base href="/" />
```